# Query on a custom table Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to do a page restricted by a token. I created a custom table on the Wordpress Database and I'm trying to use it but I don't know where it doesn't work. I created this page from scratch and not with the help of Wordpress.

Here's the code :

```
global $wpdb;

if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){
   $token = $_GET['tkn'];
   $today = date("Y-m-d");

   $resultat = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM {$wpdb->prefix}token WHERE token_name = \''.$token.'\'', ARRAY_A);
}
```

The problem is, when I use `echo $resultat['token_name'].' '.$resultat['token_dateexp'];` it returns nothing. 
It seems that even if I use `global $wpdb` my query doesn't work.
I tried with `$resultat = $wpdb->get-results('SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}token', ARRAY_A);` but I get the same results.

Can someone explain me where I'm wrong ?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you execute the query and confirm the token exists?

Comment: `{$wpdb->prefix}token` doesn't work in single quote, your query should be `$resultat = $wpdb->get-results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}token", ARRAY_A);`

Comment: wordpress queries are seriously painful. Also try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for wordpress related issues you might encounter.

Comment: what is your table name??

Comment: Thank you @Noman ! It worked.
I was sure the token existed but it was my query which was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always prepare your queries. please. Even though the wordpress method is hacky as hell under the hood.

```
if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){
   $token = $_GET['tkn'];
   $today = date("Y-m-d");
   $table = "${wpdb->prefix}token";
   $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM $table WHERE token_name = %s", $token);
   $resultat = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_A);
}
```

Also, you were using single quotes in your query. PHP does **not** evaluate variables in single quoted strings. In double quoted strings PHP does.

```
$term = 'world';
echo "Hello $term"; // outputs Hello world
echo 'hello $term'; // outputs Hello $term
```

Comment: Good suggestion mate :)

Comment: I'm new to getting my hands into PHP and Wordpress code so thank you for your advice. I'll remember to use double quote instead of single quote.

Comment: @Panchoa Promise me you will **never** use query variables other than table name or fields names as inline string variables. Use the `$wpdb->prepare` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ to insert variables and ALL user input into the queries. Please become a secure plugin coder. Might seem bothersome, but it helps doing it the right way from the start.

Comment: Yeah I promise. I didn't know this way to do but thank to you now I know. And I agree the best way to start is to do the right way, which is the most secure one.

Comment: Good :-) welcome to the world wordpress plugins. Can be fun to code for at times, frustrating at others. When you want your code you wrote looked over when you're done I suggest you post on on codereview.stackexchange.com and get the tips of the experts, who can point out areas of improvement. Will definately help with learning the important things.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep that in mind. I'm always hungry to learn new stuff and to do it the right way. When I'm done I will post it on codereview !